# Как с помощью аннотации типов указать что элементы списка неизменяемые?

Tags: python, типизация

Требуется указать для списка, что все его элементы принадлежат к неизменяемым типам:

```py
list[<...>]
```

Требуется именно "категория", наподобие `list[typing.Immutable]` (взял из головы). А не перечислять все типы.

Не смог найти информацию в интернете, также копался в модуле `typing`.

Есть мысль обойтись собственным решением:

```py
Immutable = str | int | bool | ...
list[Immutable]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мой взгляд, лучшим решением будет объявить Immutable вот так:

```py
Immutable = typing.Hashable
```

Человеку, который читает код, неизменяемость элементов будет понятна из названия, а так как hashable объект обязан быть неизменяемым, то mypy будет высвечивать соответствующее предупреждение при нарушении типизации.

```py
my_list: list[Immutable] = [...]
```

Других вариантов обозначить неизменяемость с помощью typing нет.

Comment: Это легко обходится, если создать свой мутабельный класс с методом `__hash__` (хотя конечно это будет мощный выстрел в ногу из ракетомёта)

Comment: Спасибо. Всё равно как-то странно что такая вещь не встроена в тот же typing.